# why snapshot is failled with error : Indices don\'t have primary shards +[[myindex]]

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, snapshot

when I trying to take snapshot it is failed with the following error:

```
{
  snapshot: {
    snapshot: '1430395938305_3032015',
    indices: ['myindex'],
    state: 'FAILED',
    reason: 'Indices don\'t haveprimaryshards+[ [
      myindex
    ]]
  ',
  start_time: '2015-04-30T12: 12: 18.435Z',
  start_time_in_millis: 1430395938435,
  end_time: '2015-04-30T12: 12: 18.525Z',
  end_time_in_millis: 1430395938525,
  duration_in_millis: 90,
  failures: [],
  shards: {
    total: 0,
    failed: 0,
    successful: 0
  }
}
}
```

can any one knows what wrong with it?

this is my cluster health

```
 {
"cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
"status" : "red",
"timed_out" : false,
"number_of_nodes" : 1,
"number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
"active_primary_shards" : 95,
"active_shards" : 95,
"relocating_shards" : 0,
"initializing_shards" : 0,
"unassigned_shards" : 138
}
```

when i check the health of my cluster the above was the result

```
index   shard prirep state      docs   store ip            node  
myindex 2     p      STARTED     340 152.9kb 192.168.0.120 Raman 
myindex 2     r      UNASSIGNED                                  
myindex 0     p      UNASSIGNED                                  
myindex 0     r      UNASSIGNED                                  
myindex 3     p      STARTED     262 166.9kb 192.168.0.120 Raman 
myindex 3     r      UNASSIGNED                                  
myindex 1     p      UNASSIGNED                                  
myindex 1     r      UNASSIGNED                                  
myindex 4     p      STARTED     279 170.4kb 192.168.0.120 Raman 
myindex 4     r      UNASSIGNED
```

This was i got when i excecuted /_cat/shards/myindex?v

Comment: If you do `GET /_cluster/health` what do you see? Paste the output in the post.

Comment: i pasted it in question now

Comment: Where? :-) Have you executed that command? The output of that doesn't look like what it is now in the question.

Comment: sorry. just now i pasted

Comment: The cluster is red. So, you have primary shards missing. If you do `GET /_cat/shards/myindex?v` what you get?

Comment: You need to have all the primary shard available for the index to be possible to take the snapshot. Having `p` (primary) shards as `UNASSIGNED` means the shard is not available.

Comment: Do you have any nodes that are stopped?

Comment: ya. I have three machines in LAN and now those two are stopped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76654/discussion-between-rams-and-andrei-stefan).

Comment: Then, there you go, maybe you have on those machines pieces of data that are simply not available because they are stopped.

Comment: i have the same problem when they started also.

Comment: when they started also my machine elasticsearch node  directory showing 0 node only            the location of node directory is  elasticsearch-1.2.2\data\elasticsearch\nodes

Comment: When you created `myindex` which nodes were in the cluster. You need to have the same nodes started and in the same cluster.

Comment: i have only one cluster named **elasticsearch**. My three machines also have same cluster